# Why didn’t Rem die when she killed the criminal to save misa when she was in higuchi’s car?

Tags: death-note

Shinigamis die when they kill a person to save an another person but what I don’t get is don’t shinigamis already do that on like daily basis?? They always kill people to get their remaining life span so if any person is saved in the process shinigamis don’t die. And also, Rem killed that one criminal when she was following higuchi and misa was trying to make him think she has the eyes. Wouldn’t that also count as saving misa and Rem should did for doing that?

Answer (score 6):

> Shinigamis die when they kill a person to save an another person but what I don’t get is don’t shinigamis already do that on like daily basis

the difference is intent, the intent being to extend someone's life.

> If the god of death decides to use the Death Note to kill the assassin of an individual he favors, the individual's life will be extended, but the god of death will die.

Source: [Rules of the Death Note/Manga Chapter Rules > Volume 4 > How to use XVII (Point 1)](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note/Manga_Chapter_Rules#Volume_4)

> If a god of death intentionally does the above manipulation to effectively lengthen a human's life span, the god of death will die, but even if a human does the same, the human will not die.

Source: [Rules of the Death Note/Manga Chapter Rules > Volume 10 > How to use LVIII (Point 2)](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note/Manga_Chapter_Rules#Volume_10)

when Shinigami kill normally they will always affect people's livespans however if their intent is to extend a human's life then they are going against their very purpose

> Shinigami can also save other humans they care about if that person is about to die; however, the purpose of a Shinigami is to end life, not to give it. Any Shinigami who goes against this will be killed

Source: [Shinigami > General information > Nature and abilities (2nd paragraph)](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Shinigami#Nature_and_abilities)

in [Season 1 Episode 21 "Performance"](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Performance) Misa's life wasn't in danger of being killed by either Kyosuke Higuchi or Ginzo Kanabochi. the purpose of killing Kanabochi was to make true Misa's claim to Higuchi that she was the second Kira